# Saving an array as a local variable in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So I need to figure out a way to save an array as a local variable and return it at the end of the method.  I am a bit confused,  I have been told I have two other options besides what I tried myself.  I could either store the array as a variable or use a hashtable.  I would like to to save the array as a local variable.

Below is the method I am using to try to save the return as a local variable array.

```
private Integer[] longestLength(int col, boolean color, int row) {
    // longest equals length of the longest route
    // count equals number of the longest routes
    // possible equals number of spots, that you can play off of.
    int longest = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int possible = 0;
    //this for loop counts to 4, the patterns of the 4 possible wins
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        int length = lengthOfColor(col, color, i, row)[0];
        //if a new longest is found, its new value is now set to itself
        if (length > longest) {
            longest = length;
            count = 0;
            possible = lengthOfColor(col, color, i, row)[1];
        }
        //if length is the same as longest, we increase the count, and make possible equal too the larger one
        if (longest != 0 && length == longest) {
            count++;
            possible = Math.max(lengthOfColor(col, color, i, row)[1], possible);
        }
    }
    return new Integer[]{longest, count, possible};
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: declare an array inside the method, store in it whatever  you want to and then return it at the end of the method

Answer (score 0):

```
// int col; boolean color; int row;
Integer[] result;
result = longestLength(col, color, row);
```

The local variable `result` would hold the return value of `longestLength()`.

Answer (score 0):

Like you just said there's nothing wrong with your actual code.

But if you want to use a local variable you just need to declare a new array inside your method, put these values on it, then return it, so inside your method do the following.

```
// declare a local array in your method
Integer[] output = new Integer[3]();

// put the values you need inside your array
output[0] = new Integer(longest);
output[1] = new Integer(count);
output[2] = new Integer(possible;);

// finally return it
return output;
```

**Note:**

Remember to cast your values to `Integer` when you add them to this array because they are of type `int` .

Comment: @Brentonr25 did this answer help you? if so please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shown so far you do not need to use the boxed primitive Integer. Here are two versions of what you can do.

```
Integer[] myIntegerArray = longestLength(col, color, row);
```

A better way would be to change your method to `private int[] longestLength(int col, boolean color, int row)` and for it to return `new int[]{longest, count, possible};`

```
int[] myIntArray = longestLength(col, color, row);
```

The difference between the two is that there is a slight overhead with Integer vs int. So using int would be faster than Integer when you do not need an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
private Integer[] longestLength(int col, boolean color, int row) {
    Integer array[]=new Integer[size]; // make an array
    // Do your work
    .............

    return array; // return the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks straight forward, what I am understanding is that you need to create a local array which can save the value from a method as you shown in the code.

You just need to create a local array (as "longestRouteCount" mentioned in below code)with the same data type in your case Integer, then call the method assigning the return value to the local array variable.

```
Integer longestRouteCount [];
longestRouteCount = longestLength(longest, count, possible);
```

Please share if you had the same query, otherwise please elaborate more. 
If you think this answer helped you, please vote.